# angular2 cordova safari web inspector reload errors

Tags: sqlite, cordova, angular

I'm trying to setup an app with cordova, angular2 and sqlite,

using **cordova emulate ios**, the app loads perfectly fine and the same for **npm start**.

If I comment out,

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

I can get logs from,

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', location: 'default'});
    db.transaction(function(tr) {
        tr.executeSql("SELECT upper('Test string') AS upperString", [], function(tr, rs) {
            console.log('Got upperString result: ' + rs.rows.item(0).upperString);
        });
    });
});
```

in **safari web inspector**, if I don't comment out the afore mentioned script tags when I reload the web inspector I get,

> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (index.css, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (shim.min.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (zone.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (Reflect.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (system.src.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: System   global code
>   (index.html:15)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (systemjs.config.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (index.js, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (cordova.js, line 0)

I'm wondering why the web inspector can't find the resources and how I resolve this issue?

Comment: PATH file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/784E3FBC-7505-43AC-8001-53DA17A20499/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5409C155-B324-4A6F-91A4-2EDA8517281F/sqlite-app.app/www/index.html/css/index.css,    should index.html be in the full path? i don't think it should how do i alter the path?

Comment: i changed the cordova config.xml default <content src="index.html"/> to '<content src="http://localhost:3000"/>', now when i reload web inspector the simulator no longer displays a blank app and i no longer get the previous errors however i'm getting a new error, [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (cordova.js, line 0) 'http://localhost:3000/cordova.js'

Answer (score 0):

ok i found out what's causing the issue the @angular/router.

when i remove routing from @ngmodules imports,

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i get no error messages when reloading safari web inspector and everything loads in fine.